# Selenium using IE11, getting Unable to find element with id == lst-ib , server did not provide any stacktrace information

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "d://IEDriverServer.exe");
  WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
  driver.get("http://www.google.com");

  WebElement textbox;
  WebElement buton;
  textbox = driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib"));
  textbox.sendKeys("Mindtree");
  buton = driver.findElement(By.id("sblsbb"));
  buton.click();
```

Unable to find element with id == lst-ib (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

this is working fine with firefox.

Comment: Please provide a bit of background on what what you did leading up to this

Comment: @Bendy - I think OP is just searching string "Mindtree" in google and click on search button.

Comment: I checked your code with IE9 and IE 11 (11.0.9600.17801). It works fine for me in both cases. InternetExplorerDriver server (32-bit) 2.45.0.0.